# Python multiprocessing with arrays and multiple arguments

Tags: python-2.7, multidimensional-array, python-multiprocessing, h5py

So I am trying to read in a bunch of very large data files and each one takes quite some time to load. I am trying to figure out how to load them in the quickest way and without running into memory problems. Once the data files are loaded into the array the correct way I do not need to write to them, but just need to read. I've been trying to parallelize this for some time, but can't figure it out.

Let's say I have 400 time files. Each of these files is tab separated and has 30 variables each with 40,000 data points. I would like to create a 400x30x40000 array so that I can access the points easily. 
The data file is set up so that the first 40k points is for variable 1, the second 40k is for var 2, and so on.

I have written a function that loads in a time file correctly and stores it in my array correctly. What I'm having trouble with is parallelizing it. This does work if I put it in a for loop and iterate over i.

```
import h5py
import pandas as pd
h5file = h5py.File('data.h5','a')
data = h5file.create_dataset("default",(len(files),len(header),numPts))
       # is shape 400x30x40000
def loadTimes(files,i,header,numPts,data):
   # files has 400 elements
   # header has 30 elements
   # numPts is an integer
   allData = pd.read_csv(files[i],delimiter="\t",skiprows=2,header=None).T
   for j in range(0,len(header)):
      data[i,j,:] = allData[0][j*numPts:(j+1)*numPts]
   del allData
```

files is the list of time files loaded by `subprocess.check_output` (has about 400 elements), header is the list of variables, loaded from another file (has 30 elements in it). numPts is the number of points per variable (so around 40k).

I've tried using `pool.map` to load the data but found it didn't like multiple arguments. I also tried using partial, zip, and the lambda function, but none of those seem to like my arrays.

I am not set in stone about this method. If there is a better way to do it I will greatly appreciate it. It will just take too long to load in all this data one at a time. My calculations show that it would take ~3hrs to load on my computer using one core. And I will use up A LOT of my memory. I have access to another machine with a lot more cores, which is actually where I will be doing this, and I'd like to utilize them properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So how I solved this was using the h5 file format. What I did was write the loops so that they only had the iter

```
def LoadTimeFiles(i):
   from pandas import read_csv
   import h5py as h5
   dataFile = h5.File('data.h5','r+')
   rFile = dataFile['files'][i]
   data = dataFile['data']
   lheader = len(data[0,:,0])
   numPts = len(data[0,0,:])
   allData = read_csv(rFile,delimiter="\t",skiprows=2,header=None,low_memory=False).T
   for j in range(0,lheader):
      data[i,j,:] = allData[0][j*numPts:(j+1)*numPts]
   del allData
   dataFile.close()

def LoadTimeFilesParallel(np):
   from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
   import h5py as h5
   files = h5.File('data.h5','r')
   numFiles = len(files['data'][:,0,0])
   files.close()
   pool = Pool(np)
   freeze_support
   pool.map(LoadTimeFiles,range(numFiles))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   np = 5
   LoadTimeFilesParallel(np)
```

So since I was storing the data in the h5 format anyway I thought I'd be tricky and load it up in each loop (I can see no time delays in reading the h5 files). I added the option `low_memory=False` to the `read_csv` command because it made it go faster. The j loop was really fast so I didn't need to speed it up.

Now each `LoadTimeFile` loop takes about 20-30 secs and we do 5 at once without order mattering. My ram never hits above 3.5Gb (total system usage) and drops back to under a gig after runs.